# Linking existing database entry/object to the property of another object from a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update a property called Municipality on an ApplicationUser.  The problem is that the Municipality property is meant to be a related object that already exists in a database table of municipalities, so I need to create a link rather than just setting the municipality property (which creates a duplicate municipality in the database)

I heard that exposing foreign keys might be the right direction (i.e. explicitly adding a MunicipalityId property to the ApplicationUser class), like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public int? MunicipalityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(MunicipalityId))]
    public Municipality Municipality { get; set; }
}
```

...but when the MunicipalityId is set with the following code, user.Municipality remains null

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SelectRegion(SelectRegionViewModel selectRegionViewModel, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        if (user == null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            user.MunicipalityId = selectRegionViewModel.SelectedMunicipality;

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
                _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
            {
                context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }
```

Are there some extra steps I need to do if I set the foreign key?  Looking at the entry in the dbo.AspNetUsers database table, it looks like the user's Municipality is already set correctly because the MunicipalityId is set, but user.Municipality is always null in the above code (even when the application is started-up with the ApplicationUser having a valid MunicipalityId)

Comment: If you want `Municipality` property to be loaded (populated), you need to explicitly request that by using `Include` method - see [Loading Related Data](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#loading-related-data)

Comment: thanks, I guess I shouldn't be using UserManager for this if it doesn't do eager loading for the additional properties.  I'll just get it working with a DbContext though, and it sounds like exposing the foreign key like this isn't an unconventional thing to do (?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was on the right track with exposing foreign keys and just needed to find a clean way of doing eager loading of the custom property Municipality on the ApplicationUser class.  I did this by creating a custom UserStore class which Includes the Municipality:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        :base(context)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return Users
            .Include(u => u.Municipality)
            .Include(u => u.Roles)
            .Include(u => u.Claims)
            .Include(u => u.Logins)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
    }
}
```

Then had the framework use this class by adding .AddUserStore in this part of the Startup ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>();
```

What this accomplishes is that the UserManager will return a user with the Municipality populated, avoiding the need to create an ApplicationDbContext and make a query in addition to my queries through the userManager

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```